# implement thread safe function object in rust

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am trying to implement some stability pattern (introduced in cloud-native-go, e.g. https://github.com/cloud-native-go/examples/blob/main/ch04/circuitbreaker.go) in rust lang.
The basic idea is to wrap a function in a closure, which keeps some states about the function call. I also want my implementation to be thread safe.

I finally come up with something like this:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
pub(crate) enum Error {
    UnReachable,
    CircuitError,
}

pub(crate) type Circuit = Arc<Mutex<dyn Fn() -> Result<String, Error>>>;

pub(crate) fn fail_after(threshold: usize) -> Circuit {
    let cnt = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let f = move || {
        let mut c = cnt.lock().unwrap();
        *c += 1;
        if *c > threshold {
            return Err(Error::CircuitError);
        } else {
            return Ok("ok".to_owned());
        }
    };
    return Arc::new(Mutex::new(f));
}

#[test]
fn test_debounce_first() {
    let c = fail_after(1);
    assert!(c.lock().unwrap()().is_ok());
    assert!(c.lock().unwrap()().is_err());
}


#[test]
fn test_debounce_first_data_race() {
    let c = fail_after(1);
    let mut results = vec![];
    for _ in 0..10 {
        let d1 = Arc::clone(&c);
        let h = thread::spawn(move || {
            let r: Result<String, Error> = d1.lock().unwrap()();
            r
        });
        results.push(h)
    }

    for result in results {
        let r = result.join().unwrap();
        assert!(r.is_ok())
    }
}
```

([rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=24fb1bf3df708fce74fd83220fce626b))

The multi thread test give compile error:

```
error[E0277]: `(dyn Fn() -> Result<String, Error> + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/lib.rs:41:17
    |
41  |         let h = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `(dyn Fn() -> Result<String, Error> + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `(dyn Fn() -> Result<String, Error> + 'static)`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Sync` for `Mutex<(dyn Fn() -> Result<String, Error> + 'static)>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `Arc<Mutex<(dyn Fn() -> Result<String, Error> + 'static)>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:41:31: 44:10]`
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
```

I wonder how can I resolve this? I have already wrapped the function object with `Arc` and `Mutex`, why the compiler still complains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: change `dyn Fn() -> Result<String, Error>` to `dyn Fn() -> Result<String, Error> + Send + 'static`. The original definition of the type makes no guarantees about how long the `dyn Fn` lives or whether or not it can be sent between threads safely.

<s>Another note, you're probably going to have to further modify it to `Box<dyn Fn() -> Result<String, Error> + Send + 'static>` since I see you're constructing your `Mutex` with `new` which requires the type it contains to be `Sized`, however `dyn Trait` is unsized. I have never tried constructing a mutex with an unsized type so you may need to look into that further.</s>

#### Edit

You don't need to box the `dyn Fn() -> _` because the `Arc<Mutex<_>>` is initially constructed with the concrete closure, but then coerces to the unsized `Mutex<dyn Fn() -> _>` due to the third blanket implementation mentioned [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html) and `Arc`'s [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/sync.rs.html#249) of `CoerceUnsized`.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `Send` and `'static` make it compile.
Somehow `Box` is not needed to new a Mutex.

Comment: Ah yeah, digging into it a little more that works because you're constructing an `Arc<Mutex<impl Fn() -> ..>>` which coerces to `Arc<Mutex<dyn Fn() -> ..>>` due to `Arc`'s impl of `CoerceUnsized` and the blanket impls of `Unsize`.